# Suppress User-facing text should use localized string macro warning

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode8

I am using unlocalized strings and getting below warning

> User-facing text should use localized string macro

How to suppress this warning ?

Comment: You should change the correct answer to HogDotMac's - its a single change to the project file, versus possibly hundreds of changes to every user facing string in your project. Hopefully at least others will see this comment to get the proper answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

in the project Build Settings:
"Static Analyzer - Issues - Apple APIs"
set "Missing Localizability" to No

also make sure to not have any Localizations, otherwise will xcode 9 will warn you to turn on "Missing Localizability" analyzer warnings again.

this was trickier for me, i had to open the project file (project.pbxproj) with a text editor and manually empty the list of "knownRegions" otherwise they would not stay deleted

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 33):

From [clang documentation](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/faq.html#unlocalized_string):

> you can suppress the analyzer warnings (and document your intent) with a function that just returns its input but is annotated to return a localized string:
>
> ```
> __attribute__((annotate("returns_localized_nsstring")))
> static inline NSString *LocalizationNotNeeded(NSString *s) {
>   return s;
> }
>
> [field setStringValue:LocalizationNotNeeded(@"Debug")];
> ```
>
> Some projects may also find it useful to use NSLocalizedString but add "DNL" or "Do Not Localize" to the string contents

Comment: Nice. Are there similar warnings in Swift? And if yes, what is the syntax equivalent of that `returns_localized_nsstring` in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

Or just do use a localized string macro as suggested by Xcode:

```
 NSLocalizedString(@"My string that was giving me warnings", nil)
```

Comment: This is not a recommended way as including the macro will automatically track the string as a translatable via included translation tools for example.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is this:

```
[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Debug"];
```